# How do I assert a DCG rule in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg

The following Prolog prints `done` for goals `test1` and `test2`, but not `test3`. My understanding is that `match_test2` and `match_test3` in this code should be equivalent. How do I create a DCG rule via an assertion?

```
setup(['t','e','s','t']).

match_test1 --> ['t','e','s','t'].
test1 :-
    setup(C),
    phrase(match_test1,C),
    write("done").

test2 :-
    setup(C),
    assert(match_test2(['t','e','s','t'],[])),
    phrase(match_test2,C),
    write("done").

test3 :-
    setup(C),
    assert(match_test3 --> ['t','e','s','t']),
    phrase(match_test3,C),
    write("done").
```

Using SWI-Prolog version 7.2.3 for x86_64-darwin14.3.0, running as `swipl -l bug.pl -t test1` (or `test2`, `test3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `expand_term/2` to **translate** the DCG to a regular clause first:

```
?- expand_term(match_test1 --> [t,e,s,t], Clause).
Clause =  (match_test1([t, e, s, t|_1498], _1498):-true).
```

Then use `assertz/1` as usual on `Clause`, i.e., `assertz(Clause)`.

Note that you can write down the atoms directly, i.e., instead of `'e'`, simply write `e`.

In addition, consider setting `double_quotes` to **`chars`** by adding the directive:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

Now you can write, very conveniently:

```
?- T = "test".
T = [t, e, s, t].
```

This syntax is very nice and makes DCGs a lot easier to debug and work with.